# How to solve this 'cipher' puzzle for kids

Tags: cipher

I was told this is a puzzle for kids. The answer is 'HACKER'. How does one obtain the key (and/or "decode the cipher")?

> Decode this cipher: The letters of the alphabet are being represented by other letters, so take a closer look to find the patterns underneath the letters.

[image: "A" corresponds to "J". The word to decode is encoded by PJONFR]

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide [proper attribution](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7259/proper-attribution-for-non-original-puzzles-a-guide) for this question?

Comment: There's something weird about the lower case L's in the image. Might be relevant....

Comment: @cap good spot but I guess it's an **I** as in IMO. Like the text, the **I** in the grid is the only one that doesn't have smoothed edges.

Comment: I suggest looking at Page 30...

Comment: This is clearly too short so solve with cryptanalysis, so there must be some other information we are meant to find. Given the reference to answers on page 30, this looks like a scan from a book. I'm wondering if "the patterns underneath the letters" is meant to be taken literally, and there was something faint in the original that hasn't survived in this scan?